# Multivariate Time series autoregressive series using StatsModels in Python: What to do after fitting the model?

Tags: python, excel, statsmodels

Good day

This is my maiden Stack Overflow question so I hope I get it right and don't break any rules.

I work as a Fund Manager so do not have computer science background. I am however learning python at the moment.

I am trying to fit historical data which includes multiple time series. I think I have managed to do this. The thing I need to do next is to use this data to predict values into the future for these time series. I have looked at the StatsModels documentation but can't quite make heads or tails of it.

I am using xlwings and linking to excel. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels
import pandas

def Fit_the_AR():
    dataRange = Range('Sheet1','rDataToFit').value
    dateRange = Range('Sheet1', 'rDates').value
    titleRange = Range('Sheet1', 'rTitles').value
    ARModel = statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR(dataRange,dateRange,titleRange,freq='m')
    statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.fit(ARModel,1, 'ols', None, 'c', True)
    Range('Sheet2','B2').value = ARModel.endog_names
    Range('Sheet2','B3').value = ARModel.endog
```

I thought i would have to use the predict method but not sure how I get all the parameters required for it.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated. I can provide an excel file of the data if need be. Thank you.

Comment: did you look at http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#forecasting ? There doesn't seem to be a runable example in the documentation.